# Understanding Shimura correspondence in context of Langlands functoriality

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, half-integral-weight

Recently, I started to read about automorphic forms and representations on covering groups, e.g. metaplectic groups. I set my first goal as understanding Shimura's correspondence in representation theoretic setup, and I have few questions on it. FYI, I'm reading Weissman's articles on L-groups of covering groups, and also Gelbart's *Weil's Representation and the Spectrum of Metaplectic group*.

To understand Shimura's correspondence in context of Langland's functoriality, it seems natural (at least for me) to understand $L$-group or dual group of a 2-cover of $G = \mathrm{GL}_{2}$ (let's say $\tilde{G}$) and a map ${}^{L}\tilde{G} \to {}^{L}\mathrm{GL}_{2}$ that corresponds to Shimura's correspondence. However, understanding definition of $L$-groups for covering groups (by Weissman) requires me to understand Brylinski-Deligne theory first, which is a little abstract and general for my purpose. It would be great if someone could explain the $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$ and metaplectic case in a rather concrete way.

Here's what I (kind of) understand until now, from Section 4 and 5 of Gelbart's book. The classification of admissible irreducible representations of $\tilde{G}$ is very similar to that of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}$, and most of them comes from subquotient of principal series representations induced from two quasi-characters. And the representation theoretic version of Shimura's correspondence is something like: for a given irreducible (admissible) unitary representation $\tilde{\pi}$ of $\tilde{G}(F)$ ($F$ is a local field), it "is" a subquotient of a principal series representation $\tilde{\rho}(\mu_1, \mu_2)$, and the corresponding representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(F)$ is one that is a subquotient of $\rho(\mu_1^2, \mu_2^2)$. Hence, in some sense, Shimura's correspondence is something like squaring the characters that parametrizing representations. Since it is quite simple (rather technical), I think this may corresponds to some simple map between ${}^{L}{\tilde{G}} \to {}^{L} \mathrm{GL}_{2}$.